# Spring Security 6 Form Login does not create a login controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying integrate the default spring security 6 form login as described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html#page-title with my Spring 6 MVC (not boot!)

I expect that there would be a `GET /login` controller for the login page and a `POST /login` controller for a login form action. The `GET` controller should return a login form with `action="/login"` and `mehod="post"`.

Neither controller gets created. A browser `GET /login` returns

```
HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found
URI:    /login
STATUS: 404
MESSAGE:    Not Found
SERVLET:    Spring Dispatcher Servlet
```

I also tried a configuration with custom login page with a form that `POST`s the credentials to `/login` but the server returns

```
HTTP ERROR 405 Method 'POST' is not supported.
URI:    /login
STATUS: 405
MESSAGE:    Method 'POST' is not supported.
SERVLET:    Spring Dispatcher Servlet
```

**SpringSecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.myapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.LogoutConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/secured")
                        .hasAnyRole("USER")
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                // Replacing Customizer.withDefaults() with form -> form.loginPage('/login').permitAll() 
                // doesn't work either 
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I searched a lot and finally found the solution. Just add this piece of code:

```
   .formLogin(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer::permitAll)
```